# If $\mathbf{k,r}\in \mathbb{R}^3$, then $\mathbf{k\cdot r= k'\cdot r = k''\cdot r}\to \mathbf{k',k'',k,r}$ are coplanar.

Tags: vectors

If $\mathbf{k,r}$ are fixed vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, show that $\mathbf{k\cdot r= k'\cdot r = k''\cdot r}$ implies that $\mathbf{k',k'',k,r}$ are coplanar.

I encountered this theorem in a physical situation. I have physical arguments (the $\bf{k}$'s represent wavenumbers), but wanted to prove it.

Note that subtracting two of the three expressions yields:

$$\mathbf{(k-k')\cdot r= (k-k'')\cdot r = (k'-k'')\cdot r} = 0.$$
This means that $\bf{k-k'}$ and $\bf{k-k''}$ lie perpendicular to $\bf{r}$, i.e. they should span a space (line or plane) perpendicular to $\bf{r}$. From here I don't see why all these vectors should lie on the same plane.

Comment: I'm afraid $r$ should not be regarded as coplanar with the other three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.  Let $r = k = \langle 1, 0, 0 \rangle$, $k' = \langle 1,1,0 \rangle$, $k'' = \langle 1, 1, 1 \rangle$.  Then $k$, $k'$, $k''$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

EDIT: If you did mean to say that the terminal points of the vectors are coplanar, you can modify by keeping $k$, $k'$, $k''$ and taking $r = \langle 2, 0, 0 \rangle$, so it is still not true.

Comment: the plane refers to the locations of the arrowheads of the vectors. The plane here is $x=1$

Comment: it would not be $r$ itself, it would be a scalar multiple of $r$ given by the point where the plane intersects the line through $r$

Comment: @WillJagy That is very different from what the OP said.  And if he did intend to make that statement, then he has already proven it.  (Assuming that the vectors are distinct and nonzero).

Comment: Agreed, he did not write the thing well.